# Scheduled task - no next run time

Tags: python, win32com

here is my problem. When I create a new scheduled task using win32com in python there is no next run time for the task. It says 'never' in task scheduler gui.

My workflow of creating tasks:

1. try to make new task, if failed, get existing one for update,
2. create daily triggers for the task,
3. save it all.

Any advice?

Comment: i would start by trying to get existing task first, before creating one

Comment: good advice, but this is not the problem. I need to start the task, and it seems, that not having next run time defined causes the task not to start.

Answer (score 2):

So here is the simple solution.

I checked the defaults params for the trigger and than I saw, that Flags is set to 4, which means DISABLED.

It seems, that's the default setting for a new trigger for a task.